# Apply cache-control to a specific files in directory

Tags: .htaccess, no-cache

I want the all files from a directory have cache,

I have this in my **.htaccess** but not working correctly

```
<FilesMatch /js/admin/.*>
    Header set cache-control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable"
</FilesMatch>
```

What is the correct solution?